# Can we inject $http in to a Angular Service and pass that data to a controller?

Tags: angularjs, json, http, angular-services, angular-controller

I am trying to load JSON data from an external file using a service in AngularJS.

```
myApp.service('ContactsListService', function($http) {
    var contactsList = $http.get('js/contacts.json').success(function(data){
    return data;
    });
    console.log(contactsList); // prints some $http object 
    return {
    'contactsList': contactsList;
    };
}

myApp.controller('ContactDisplayController',['$scope','ContactsListService',function($scope, ContactsListService){
$scope.contacts = ContactsListService.contactsList;
console.log(ContactsListService.contactsList); // prints 'undefined' here
}]);

**JSON file:**

        [
          {
            name: 'Steph Curry',
            mobile: '111111111'
          },
          {
           name: 'Lebron James',
           mobile: '2323232323'
         }
     ]
```

I want to use the data from the service in the controller, I am unable pass that data. Correct me if I am injecting the service in an incorrect way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the $http promise rather than the response from that ajax call. A better approach would be for the service to define a method that returned the promise, and for your controller to get that promise and use the result.

```js
myApp.service('ContactsListService', function($http) {
  this.getContactsList = function() {
    return $http.get('js/contacts.json');
  };
});

myApp.controller('ContactDisplayController',['$scope','ContactsListService',function($scope, ContactsListService){
  ContactsListService.getContactsList().success(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Joey, I have tried in your way, I am unable to print data outside the success function:
`myApp.controller('ContactDisplayController',['$scope','ContactsListService',function($scope, ContactsListService){
  ContactsListService.getContactsList().success(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
   console.log($scope.contacts); // prints data here.
  });
console.log($scope.contacts); // prints undefined here.
}]);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Joey, I have tried in your way, I am unable to print data outside the success function:

```
myApp.controller('ContactDisplayController',['$scope','ContactsListService',function($scope, ContactsListService){
  ContactsListService.getContactsList().success(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
   console.log($scope.contacts); // prints data here.
  });
console.log($scope.contacts); // prints undefined here.
}]);
```

Comment: That's cause the second console.log executes before the result comes back from the ajax request. It is correct that contacts IS undefined a t that time.

Comment: Use comments/edits to your answer, rather than posting an answer to your question. Your `console.log` is executed before you have data as you are using async ajax to get the data

Comment: Thank you KreepN, @JoeyCiechanowicz for the explanation and answer. Totally got it.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to know how this is flowing.  Get the data, then do something with it, right there in the handling of that data.

```
myApp.controller('ContactDisplayController',['$scope','ContactsListService',function($scope, ContactsListService){
     $scope.contacts = [];  //initialize it
      ContactsListService.getContactsList().success(function(data) {
        $scope.contacts = data;
         //now do stuff with it
      });
     //console logging here happens before your async call returns
    }]);
```